# Square API - Possible to have a callback after a successful order?

Tags: webhooks, square-connect

I have a business that uses the Square Stand and loves the functionality. They don't want to change anything about how they process orders.

However, they use CRM to do their email marketing and contact management. So they are currently manually inputting orders that are made from Square into their CRM.

What I would want to do for them is have them keep using their Square stand as usual, but on the back end have some script that gets called upon any time a successful order is made on their square stand, which will then use the CRM API to input the order automatically.

Is such a configuration possible? If not, what would be the workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Square currently has a [webhooks](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/?q=webhook#webhooks-overview) implementation that provides what you're asking for (notifications when a payment occurs). At present, it unfortunately does not include the full payment details, and so your script would need to call the [payments API](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#navsection-transaction) to obtain the full details when a payment occurs.

--da3mon

Comment: Does it give enough info so that using the payments API I could look that info up based on the webhook?

Also, does this allow me to use the iOS or Android Register app and have access to these webhooks? I would want to make this so that the end user could use the Square Register App and have access to webhooks. That would be great for me and save a lot of work.

Comment: Reading through a bit more and tinkering with the API, it seems this a bit more complicated than I thought. I am using PHP, so the webhook uses connect v1 API, but it appears that to access contact info, I have to user connect v2 API. So if I understand correctly, I have to user both v1 and v2 API's simultaneously so that I could read use the payment ID from the webhook to look up the payment. From that, grab almost everything except the contact info. For that would have to use the tender ID and use the v2 API to pull up the contact info. Does that sound right?